# What is the difference between WSGI and API?

Tags: api, wsgi

I hail from non programming, non computer science background and am learning software engineering for data science. As a part of the learning, when I started to learn Flask Framework, I came across WSGI. After learning about the definition of WSGI, I found it similar to API as API is the middle layer between client and server and WSGI is the middle layer between web server and web app.

I was checking for the difference between both to make sure my understanding is correct however I was unable to find the answer. Hence I hope I will find the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

WSGI is a standard interface which allows to seperate server code from the application code where you add your business logic. WSGI succeeded in allowing much more freedom and innovation in the Python web space.

In WSGI applications takes a single request and returns response at a time. This single and synchronous callable limits WSGI for long lived connections like websocket connections. Even if we made the application asynchronous callable it only has a single path to provide request.

API is the acronym for Application Programming Interface, which is a software intermediary that allows two applications to talk to each other. Each time you use an app like Facebook, send an instant message, or check the weather on your phone, you’re using an API.

Comment: I would like to know the definition of API shared by you a bit more. You have mentioned software intermediary, so is API a software? or is it an interface?